# Sign out a user OneDrive API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I want to sign out a user in OneDrive API, I tried [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/getting-started/msa-oauth?view=odsp-graph-online#sign-the-user-out), I sent the request:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://login.live.com/oauth20_logout.srf?client_id=762d0c10-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-085a4a1743bc&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine((int)response.StatusCode);
Console.WriteLine(response.IsSuccessful);
```

output:

```
302
False
```

my question is how to send a logout request

Comment: what if you change it to a `PUT`?

Comment: Then status code is `404` @JohnB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OAuth is inherently stateless so there is really nothing to "sign out" of. When you complete the OAuth flow you receive a token back. That token is used to authenticate the user *every time* you call the API. If you don't include the token in the Authorization header, the API will reject your request.

So to "sign out", simply wipe any stored access token values from your app's memory/storage and the app will no longer have access to that user's account.

Comment: Nope.   Not for onedrive.   Onedrive caches your login state *against* the oauth spec.   So once you sign in to onedrive, future oauth requests will succeed.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you **did not follow the rules before performing the request**:

- Delete any cached access_token or refresh_token values you've
  previously received from the OAuth flow.
- Perform any sign out actions in your application (for example,
  cleaning up local state, removing any cached items, etc.).

**Only after** can you make a call to the authorization web service using the url:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={redirect-uri}
```

After removing the cookie, the browser will be redirected to the redirect URL you provided. When the browser loads your redirect page, no authentication query string parameters will be set, and you can infer the user has been logged out.

Comment: that's a desktop app, without any browser, is there an option without redirecting? waht the meaning of deleting access_token, should I send http request for that?

Comment: I am afraid there is no way without redirect, you need to send an official question for Microsoft, as the request is requiring a redirect url. For the access token you do not need to send a request, the subject is written to details in the documentation.

Comment: Im afraid that's the question the person asked... how do i "sign out" of onedrive's cached browser access.